# MAUI Geolocation is not working in MainPage constructor

Tags: geolocation, maui

Geolocation works fine if I click a button (see below).

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace ABC;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
}

private async void GetMyLocationButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
        if (location == null)
        {
            location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest()
            {
                DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.High,
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
            });
        }

        if (location == null)
        {
            LatLonLabel.Text = "Something went wrong. Cannot get your location.";
        }
        else
        {
            LatLonLabel.Text = $"My Latitude and Longtidue: {location.Latitude}, {location.Longitude}";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

}
```

But if I add something as follows:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetMyLocationButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty); // nothing happens

}
```

When I start up app, nothing happens. The app doesn't ask for location permission. Any ideas? TIA.

Comment: The issue isn't geolocation; its trying to use an async method inside a constructor, which is not an async context. search `c# xamarin call async method from constructor` - should be able to find some earlier answers describing solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to call the `Geolocation` service in `OnAppearing()` where you can use `async` than in `constructor`. You can refer to the sample code below:

```
    protected  override async void OnAppearing() 
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await GetCurrentLocationAsync();

    }

    public async Task GetCurrentLocationAsync()

    {


        try

        {

            var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

            if (location == null)

            {

                location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest()

                {

                    DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.High,

                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)

                });

            }



            if (location == null)

            {

                LatLonLabel.Text = "Something went wrong. Cannot get your location.";

            }

            else

            {

                LatLonLabel.Text = $"My Latitude and Longtidue: {location.Latitude}, {location.Longitude}";

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }

    }
```